Tabs in Material UI indicator not showing up
I'm trying to add an indicator for my Tabs components. I'm using Material UI version 5.14.20.
Here's why my tabs look like:

The source of the tabs is very simple:
import { Tab, Tabs } from '@mui/material';

export function TabListComponent() {

   return (
      <Tabs indicatorColor='red'>
         <Tab label='Tab1' />
         <Tab label='Tab2' />
      </Tabs>
   );
}

However, the indicator is not showing up.
I've also tried all of the answers in: How to change active tab color in Material UI? and I'm still not seeing the indicator.
Is there something I need to add to get the indicator to show up?
I also tried this:
<Tabs
   TabIndicatorProps={{
      style: {
         backgroundColor: 'red',
      },
   }}
 >

And still saw no change.

That did not work. Also all of the examples in the MUI documentation do not include that property. Also the API documentation for tabs does not include that property. https://mui.com/material-ui/api/tabs/

I figured it out. There was a problem with my state variable. The selected value was coming in as a string but was expected to be an integer. I'll provide all of the details in my answer

The problem with the indicator not showing up was a problem with the value that was being passed into the Tabs value property. When you don't specify a value on a Tab the default is the child's position and that's an integer. My problem was that the state variable that I was using was storing the value as a string and so the comparison with the integer was failing. The other way to fix is to not store the selected index as a string.
Here's my quick fix:
<Tabs
   value={parseInt(selectedTab)}
   onChange={handleChange}
   indicatorColor='red'
>
   <Tab label='Tab1' />
   <Tab label='Tab2' />
</Tabs>

Now the indicator is showing up. It's still not showing as red but when I tried:
<Tabs
   TabIndicatorProps={{
      style: {
         backgroundColor: 'red',
      },
   }}
>

The indicator colored correctly
